# Embedded linux read only

Tags: linux, embedded, readonly

I'm currently working on an embedded linux device, i'm trying to make the file system read only which is fairly easy to do, but the application requires read/write access to files in `/etc` folder (mainly passwd and shadow) those cannot be moved out to the persist partition and linked back to `/etc`. I came up with a "solution" not sure if it is a good thing or not and that is why I'm posting here.

Basically what I'm planning to do is make the whole file system read only (including `/etc`), then add a file `/etc/rw-files` which will hold paths to files that require read/write privileges for the device to work properly. on each boot I will have a script go through that list of files and folder and remount them as read/write using something like this :

```
mount --bind directory directory 
mount -o remount,rw directory directory
```

i tested this, it is working and device is behaving as it should but i'm still not quite sure of the quality of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at using the [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) filesystem. In a single mount you can superimpose a small readwrite `/etc` on top of your large readonly `/etc`, and present a merged filesystem where any changes will be preserved in the upper readwrite layer directory.  It is all automatic so you don't need to identify which files need readwrite.

Comment: that was what i was going at first but i was thinking minimal ram and space usage. i'll give it another go see how it impacts the whole thing.